# Please solve the numpy problem mentioned in the body

Tags: numpy

Write a Program in Python, which accepts an numpy array of integer and divide all those array elements
by 7 which are divisible by 7 and multiply other array elements by 3.

Answer (score -2):

```
import numpy as np

def func(array):
    return np.array([item if item%7 == 0 else item*3 for item in arr ])


arr = np.array([1,7,7,4,14,21,5]) #example

func(arr)    import numpy as np
    
    arr = np.array([1,7,7,4,14,21,5]) #example
    
    result = np.array([item if item%7 == 0 else item*3 for item in arr ])
```